# onsenUIのnavigatorがChromeアプリでうまく機能していない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, google-chrome

開発環境
⇒Monacaクラウド
新規プロジェクトのテンプレート
⇒Onsen UI最小限のテンプレート(ユニバーサルアプリ対応版)

上記内容で新規プロジェクトを作成し、そのままChormeアプリビルドを行い
Choromeアプリを実行したところ、何も表示されませんでした。
（onsenuiのnavigatorがうまく機能していないように見えるんですがindex.htmlから次ページにナビゲートされてない？）
プレビュー時は正常に表示されたのですが、何が問題か分かりますでしょうか？

Comment: *※関係者様へ。誤ってアシアルブログに投稿してしまいマルチポストになってしまいました。あちらを削除して頂けたら幸いです。*とありましたが、アシアルブログに関することはアシアルブログにてお願いします。